# How to catch application switch in Modern/Metro app?

Tags: windows-runtime, lifecycle, winjs

I wonder, where is the event that's getting called when the user switches applications (or locks his tablet).

The usecase for this is that I want to pause the playing video *the moment* a user changes an app (or opens start menu).

By default, the video continues playing. And in a weird way: it doesn't have the background media attribute, so it's muted on application switch. But when you open app again, video position is incremented by precisely the time the app has been in background for.

I can pause the video on suspend, but application isn't suspended right away, so this won't be the desired user experience.

**Update**: Answer is explained in question [How to tell if JS Windows8 metro app is visible or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855715/how-to-tell-if-js-windows8-metro-app-is-visible-or-not).

Comment: You can listen for the [Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.VisibilityChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.visibilitychanged.aspx) event. I don't know if this is exposed to WinJS.

Comment: @HansPassant default video app pauses appropriately, also PressPlay video app pauses appropriately. So, I think that there should be non-workaround approach to this problem.

Comment: @RaymondChen yes, you can do it with "document.addEventListener("msvisibilitychange", msVisibilityChangeHandler, false);" (can't format code from Surface's on-screen kbd). Could you please post your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it once I've tested it.

Comment: Go ahead and post the answer yourself since you're the one who figured out the event name. (PS, to format code, go to Settings, General, Touch Keyboard, "Make the standard keyboard layout available" -> On. Then use the standard keyboard layout.)

Comment: Oh wait, turns out this is a dup: [How to tell if JS Windows8 metro app is visible or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855715/how-to-tell-if-js-windows8-metro-app-is-visible-or-not)

Comment: Oh, yes it is. Well, maybe this one will be more google-friendly, because I've searched for the answer quite extensively, but I was thinking in terms of *application switching*, not *visibility*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pause the game also when the user switches to another app in a multimon scenario, you should use `window.onblur` and `window.onfocus` events.